# How to access other row data from a cell's custom formatter in JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an `XML` data source like below,

```
<root>
    <item priceOri = "100" discount = "10"></item>
    <item priceOri = "200" discount = "110"></item>
    .
    .
    .
</root>
```

And I'm populating those data to a table using JqGrid.
the code is something like below.

```
datatype : 'xml',
colModel: [ 
  ... 
  {name:'priceOri', index:'priceOri', width:60,xmlmap : "[priceOri]", align:"center"},
  {name:'discount', index:'discount', width:60,xmlmap : "[discount]", align:"center"},
  {name:'price', index:'price', width:60,xmlmap : "[price]", align:"center", editable: true, formatter:discountFmatter},
  ...
 ]

xmlReader: {
    root: "root",
    row: "item",
    repeatitems: false
},
```

The formatter is like below.

```
function discountFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   var price;
   // do calculation based on other cell values in the same column
   //price = priceOri - discount;
   var new_format_value = price;
   return new_format_value
}
```

As in the code I need to access other values in the `item` tag to calculate the `price` section. So basically I want to access other cell values in that same row. How can I do that.

I used below code snippets but they resulted as `undefined`

```
rowObject[0]  // undefined
rowObject.priceOri //undefined
```

Can anyone show me the steps to achieve this.

**UPDATE :** I have the **JqGrid version 4.4.0** of Tony Tomov. Since I'm working on a already developed application I can't change or update that library versions. So I have to do it using the same JqGrid version 4.4.0.

Seems like Oleg's `rowObject instanceof Element ? $(rowObject).attr("priceOri") : rowObject.priceOri` is working for this requirement.

**UPDATE 2 :**  (Because `rowObject.rewards` wont work in below case)

new XML has below changed format,
       < item priceOri = "100" discount = "10" rewards = "20" >< /item >

So new formatter will be like,

```
function discountFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   var price;
   // do calculation based on other cell values in the same column
   //price = priceOri - discount - rewards;
   var new_format_value = price;
   return new_format_value
}
```

Note that I don't display the value `rewards` in the jQgrid table. So how can I achieve this.

Oleg's answer : `In case of usage old jqGrid you will have to add new column rewards. You can use hidden: true property in the column. Free jqGrid allow you to use additionalProperties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There an important problem in processing of data inside of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). The format of `rowObject` is the same as the item of input data. Thus one have to use `rowObject[0]` or `rowObject.priceOri` to process the JSON data depend on whether `repeatitems: false` was used of not. In the same way the code of custom formatter should be another to process the JSON data, which uses the next of the nodes or the attributes. One have to use `$(rowObject).find(">priceOri")` or `$(rowObject).attr("priceOri")` (the last one corresponds the format of your data).

Event more complex (for understanding) have to be the code if one uses `loadonce: true` additionally. One will have to use the expressions described above *only during processing the data loaded from the server*. The next processing (after local sorting, paging or filtering) have to use `rowObject.priceOri` notation.

I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid short after Tony have changed the licence agreement of jqGrid (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)), made the product commercial (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and have rename jqGrid to "Guriddo jqGrid JS". Since about one year of development of free jqGrid I implemented many features (the most from there are described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and readmes to every published version).

Free jqGrid holds the format of `rowObject` parameter the same as before to hold compatibility with previous versions, but the parameter `option` is extended. It contains `rowData` property with **parsed** data. To access to `priceOri` inside of custom formatter in free jqGrid one can use `options.rowData.priceOri`. Thus you can use

```
function discountFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return parseFloat(options.rowData.priceOri) -
           parseFloat(options.rowData.discount);
}
```

The code of formatter works in the same way in case of usage `loadonce: true` and it will stay working even if you would change the format of returned data from XML to JSON (for example to improve the performance of your code).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/prime.htm) uses the latest code of free jqGrid from GitHub and it displays

[image]

It uses the following code

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    function discountFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return parseFloat(options.rowData.priceOri) -
                parseFloat(options.rowData.discount);
    }

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "prime.xml",
        datatype: "xml",
        colModel: [ 
            { name: "priceOri", xmlmap: "[priceOri]" },
            { name: "discount", xmlmap: "[discount]" },
            { name: "price", xmlmap: "[price]", editable: true,
                formatter: discountFmatter }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 60, align: "center" },
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        xmlReader: {
            root: "root",
            row: "item",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: "Stack Overflow Example"
    });
});
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer @Oleg. But I have the JQgrid version 4.4.0 of Tony Tomov. And It does not contain the `rowData` peroperty for `options` parameter. But it has `getRowData()` method. But can't use it as you mentioned. So still the problem remains.

Comment: And `$(rowObject).attr("priceOri")` will only work at the first time. After filtering it will be evaluated to `undefined` as you mentioned.

Comment: @prime: I don't recommend you to use retro version 4.4.0 published in the middle of 2012. If you still can't update then you can use `rowObject instanceof Element ? $(rowObject).attr("priceOri") : rowObject.priceOri`

Comment: Please check the updated question. I need to do it using JqGrid version 4.4.0 , Is there anyway to do it with that requirement.

Comment: seems like `rowObject instanceof Element ? $(rowObject).attr("priceOri") : rowObject.priceOri` is working. But in order to use that we need a column with `priceOri` as a name. So what if I have another XML data called `rewards` which does not show in the table. and i need to use that as well in the custom formatter.
So `rowObject.rewards` will result in an `undefined` , any idea about that. :)

Comment: @prime: I can't follow you. The names `priceOri` and `discount` are the names of **another columns**, which have no direct relation to the column `price`, where you use the custom formatter. Thus you *have to specify both column names `priceOri` and `discount` somewhere explicitly. You can for example add `formatoptions: {basePrice: "priceOri", discountPrice: "discount"}` to the column `price` and use `options.colModel.formatoptions.basePrice` and `options.colModel.formatoptions.discountPrice`  inside of the code of the custom formatter to access the custom configuration properties.

Comment: @prime: Instead of `rowObject.priceOri` you will have to use index form: `rowObject[options.colModel.formatoptions.basePrice]`. I still recommend you to try to replace URLs (temporary for the test) to jqGrid files which you use in your old project: `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` and `http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js`

Comment: @prime: It seems new question. In case of usage old jqGrid you will have to add new column `rewards`. You can use `hidden: true` property in the column. Free jqGrid allow you to use `additionalProperties` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario)).

Comment: ah now I get it. But still I have to go with `hidden: true` . Thanks you for the help. really appreciate your work. :)