# How to calculate row sum on user entry in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Row sum should calculated if price or quantity is changed.
Formatter is created according to [How to access other row data from a cell's custom formatter in JqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268073/how-to-access-other-row-data-from-a-cells-custom-formatter-in-jqgrid)

In inline and row editing modes row sum doesnt change. 
Row sum column is read only and does not have id assigned. So it is difficult to create script to change it.

How to fix this so that row sum is calculated on edit ?
Testcase is in http://jsfiddle.net/ex6158L1/4/  containing

javascript

```
var serverResponse = {
        "page": "1",
        "records": "3",
        "rows": [
            { "Id": "1", Quantity:4, Price : 23.33 },
            { "Id": "2", Quantity:4.55, Price : 76.66 }

        ]
    },
    $grid = $("#categorysummary");

    function sumFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return options.rowData.Quantity *
                options.rowData.Price;
    }

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/", // use JSFiddle echo service
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST", // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    pager: '#pager',
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse) // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    },
    //colNames: ["Quantity", "Price"],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', hidden: true },
        { name: 'Quantity', editable: true},
        { name: 'Price', editable: true },
        { name: "Sum", formatter: sumFmatter,  editable: "readonly" }
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        id: 'Id',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    sortname: 'Id',
    viewrecords: true
})
.jqGrid("navGrid",'#pager')
.jqGrid("inlineNav",'#pager');
```

and css

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="pager"></div>
    <table id="categorysummary"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem, which you have, is the bug in free jqGrid, which follows that `options.rowData` was not filled inside of `setRowData`. I posted [the corresponding fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/5c5fb802788e4f871096da8d425937f7e562f010) to GitHub to eliminate the problem.

The next problem is the requirement to **reformat** the data of `editable: "readonly"`. Form editing do this, but not inline editing. One can use either `editable: "hidden"` or to add the option

```
inlineEditing: {
    extraparam: { Sum: "" }
}
```

which extend the results of inline editing with the dummy value `""` for `Sum` column. It force reformatting of the value in the `Sum` column.

I would recommend you additionally to change the formatter `sumFmatter` which you use to

```
function sumFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var quantity = parseFloat(options.rowData.Quantity || 0),
                    price = parseFloat(options.rowData.Price || 0);
    return (quantity * price).toFixed(2);
}
```

see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ex6158L1/7/ or to

```
function sumFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject, action) {
    var quantity = parseFloat(options.rowData.Quantity || 0),
        price = parseFloat(options.rowData.Price || 0);

    return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "number", quantity * price,
                             options, rowObject, action);
}
```

where I called `formatter: "number"` to format the results of the multiplication (`quantity * price`).

See the resulting demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ex6158L1/10/

Comment: How to show sum without saving row? I tried http://jsfiddle.net/gpq532w7/ . Row sum is only calculated in inline edit and only if row is saved. In form edit row sum is not displayed even if submit button is pressed. How to show correct row sum immediately if some number is entered in inline and form edit?

Comment: @Andrus: I recommended you to use `editable: "hidden"` instead of `editable: "readonly"`. You can fix the problem by usage `closeAfterAdd: true` or `closeAfterEdit: true`. Alternatively you can bind `"change"` event to both fields `"Quantity"` and `"Price"` and refresh the `Sum` on changes of Quantity or Price. I personally would not use the last choice.

Comment: `editable:hidden` removes sum field in form editing. How to show and refresh sum field in form editing without closing edit form?